# Rewrite the code without branches

Tags: c, optimization, bit-manipulation, inline

I have the following function:

```
uint16_t foo(uint8_t input)
{
     uint16_t N = 38;
     if (!(input&1))
     {
       N = 0;
     }
     else 
     {
        if ((input&2) >> 1)
        {
           N = ~N;
        }
     }
     return N;
}
```

And I would like to have it rewritten without `ifs`, just as an inline function which transforms `38` into either `0,38` or `65497` given `input` and using only standard C bit-twiddling operations.

The point is not that compiler could inline the function, or the function to be fast, but just to get rid of the branches and be constant-time regardless what the `input` is.

The first `if` is easy:

```
uint16_t c = ((input&1)^1)-1;
N &= c;
```

but I'm having troubles finding some simple way to do that conditional negation.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=cmov&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not targeting a processor which has this instruction.

Comment: Then what are you targeting? Basically, any ISA born after C language has at least one way to do `x=cond?y:z` fast, really fast.

Comment: I'm targeting an MCU - MSP430, its instruction set is very limited. The point is not to be fast, just to be constant-time, regardless what the `input` is.

Comment: Conditional one's complement by XORing with a mask of all 0s or all 1s: `N = N ^ (0 - ((input&2) >> 1))`.

Comment: You might get a much better answer, if you state the actual problem you are facing. I suspect an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: Actually, I would say the problem is stated quite clearly by the first code. There's no more science behind this function I want to use - just transforming two bits of information into either `0`,`38` or `~38`.

Comment: Read the link I provided. You just state what you think is _the_ solution. However, there might be a much easier/better one you currently are not even thinking about. (That is actually the definition of an XY-problem). As you want a fixed run-time here, there apparently _is_ more behind that! One idea might be an encryption algorithm. But even then, this would only be a small part and I do not know any such algorithm where that code might make sense. But then, there is no gain in disabling interrupts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7 operations and no multiplies, builds on njuffa's comment:

```
uint16_t bar(uint8_t input)
{
    return (0-(input&1)) & (38^(0-((input>>1)&1)));
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/AOrwGC)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All the answers were really great, but I am accepting yours, because it is almost the same code I used in the end.

Answer (score 5):

Use a table lookup.

```
uint16_t foo(uint8_t input) {
    int index= input & 0x3;
    const uint16 table[4]= {0,~38,0,38};
    return table[index];
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution - but I suggest you get rid of `int index = input & 0x3` and change the return statement to `return table[input & 0x3];`.

Comment: This is also nice, thinking a little bit more low-level, I could put those values in the stack and then address them by the `index`.

Comment: @NumberFour Putting those numbers on the stack will slow down the code because doing so will require copying each number to the stack before accessing them (at least once per the function that this resides in) and will not avoid having to copy them from somewhere (including numbers encoded into op-codes).

Comment: @BobJarvis Your suggestion should produce identical assembly code to the above for any compiler unless optimizations are turned off.

Answer (score 3):

To have guaranteed run-time and balanced code, will have to go assembler. As the MSP430 assembler is not that complicated, that will not be much of a problem. Note that things like multiplication are likely performed by a function which has *not* constant run-time.

There is little sense to avoid branches. Instead, you should balance the execution paths, e.g.using NOP (no operation). The MSP430 user's guide includes instruction timing. Note that the timing is fixed, which is different with larger CPUs like ARM where it depends on pipeline and memory timing.

General note: Doing timing through CPU cycles is most times a bad idea. Modern MCUs like MSP430 provide internal timers and connections to other peripherals like ADC to trigger e.g. conversions with a highly accurate timing. They can generate an interrupt so the CPU can prepare the next value or read the sample without caring about run-time of the code (unless it takes too long).

Using the CPU for such forbids for instance interrupt, as these will blow any timing. That makes maintenance of such a system a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your note about the interrupts. I actually realized I forgot to turn them off :)

Answer (score 2):

If I read your code in the right way, it says the following:

```
uint16_t foo1(uint8_t input)
{
     uint16_t N = 38;

     uint16_t bit0 = input & 1;
     uint16_t nbit0 = bit0 ^ 1;
     uint16_t bit1 = (input & 2) >> 1;
     uint16_t nbit1 = bit1 ^ 1;

     N = nbit0 * ( bit1 * ~N + nbit1 * N);

     return N;
}
```

Feel free to get rid of variables. They are just for readability.

Comment: Hm, looks good, the only problem would be those multiplications, which I presume could be be taken care of using `AND`s and some 0 minus 1 trick.

Comment: Yes. Or by signed shifting.

Comment: Actually, if you manage getting `bit1` as all-zeros or all-ones word, you can replace `bit1 * ~N + nbit1 * N` by just `N^bit1`

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    int N = (input&1)*(((input&2)*32729)+(38+((input&2)>>1)));
    printf("%d\n", N);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem here is that multiplication by `32729`. I need to keep using bit-wise ops only.